# How does this Codechef Factorial Solution in C work?

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand how this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int j,p,k;
    long long int n,i;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    for(k=n;k>=1;k--)
        {
            p=0;
            scanf("%lld",&i);
            for (j=5;j<=i;j*=5)
            {
               p=p+i/j;
            }
            printf("%d\n",p);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

solves this Codechef problem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL

What I'm having troubles understanding is how this loop works:

```
for (j=5;j<=i;j*=5)
            {
               p=p+i/j;
            }
```

Why is the **j** variable set to 5 and could someone walk me trough this loop if I would give the value of 60 to the **i** variable?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @lundin I am curious why the rollback? It is usually discouraged to [repeat tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and to have [salutations in the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). The other edit was to clarify which is improving the post.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You edited the title so that it didn't make sense and then you added text of your own. Both were invalid edits. Also, editing just to remove a tag in title is a minor change that doesn't substantially improve the post, as is editing to remove "thank you". "Thank you" is not a salutation. There is nothing wrong with being polite and SO does not discourage it (as opposed to adding signatures, which is discouraged).

Comment: @Lundin I did chop off too much in the title that was a mistake but it is not clear from reading the question what the goal of the code is which is important. If the link no longer works later on down the road the question does not make much sense. The meta post I added seems to include all salutations w/o distinction but I did not do an extensive search.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Still, you should not add text of your own to other people's posts. Make a comment instead, and/or nudge the poster to include more info. Anyway, I'm not going to have a rollback war over some petty edit. If you disagree with me, please flag for diamond mod attention and they can settle it. End of story.

Answer (score 3):

In short the problem is to find the number of zeroes of a factorial of number between `1` to `1000000000`.
Now take a pencil and a paper. Start with `1`. From `1` to `4` there is no `0`. First `0` occurs at `5!`. The next is at `10!` and then at `15!, 20!, .....`. This means that number of zeroes increases at the interval of `5`.

Coming to the loop

```
for (j=5;j<=i;j*=5)
{
      p=p+i/j;
}
```

See the `i` is stand for `N` here (see the question). Since number of zeroes increases at the interval of `5`, `j` is initialized to `5` and `j` will be incremented as a multiple of `5` .

Now the simple rule is that **the number of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of `N!` is simply the multiplicity of the prime factor `5` in `N!`**.

In the statement `p=p+i/j;`, same rule is followed. The author of the program incremented `j` by `5` till `N/j >= 5` leaving `N` (i.e `i`) here as it is.

```
N = i = 30
p = 30/5 + 30/(5*5) = 6  // 30/25 is 1 and does not satisfying the condition N/j >= 5
```

Comment: After reading the explanations I get that we need to find the multiples of 5 till the number in the question, but, the sample input 3 has output as 14 (as given in the codechef website). Will you please explain me how its calculated?

Comment: @Subhasish I didn't get your question.

Comment: here [link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL), please see the example section. In the sample input 3 the output is 14. I am not getting how its 14, I am sure i am missing something, dont know what.

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee; For `3` output is `0` not `14`. Look carefully. For 60, output is 14. `60/5 + 60/(5*5) = 12 + 2 = 14`

Comment: whoaa!! for the first sample input 6 there is no output given. Sorry!!

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee; Seriously! Have you read about the question's  input format? It says: *"**There is a single positive integer T on the first line of input (equal to about 100000). It stands for the number of numbers to follow**. Then there are T lines, each containing exactly one positive integer number N, 1 <= N <= 1000000000."* Please do not waste someones time like this.

Comment: wont happen again!

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm makes more sense if you understand the method they are using to find the number of trailing zeros of a factorial which is outlined in [Trailing zero Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero) and in [Factorials and Trailing Zeroes](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm). Basically relies on the insight that you need to account for all the products of `5` and `2` in the factorial expansion to discover how many zeros there will be in the end.

The algorithm to finding the number of trailing zeros in `x!` boils down to to:

1. Finding successive powers of `5`
2. Dividing `x` by the result add the truncated result to the total
3. Stop when the result of division is less than `1` or in this specific case we know this will happen when the result is greater than `x`

So if go back to the code we can find the following steps:

```
         step 3
         |    step 1
         V    V
for (j=5;j<=i;j*=5)
{
   p=p+i/j;  // step 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
p=0;
scanf("%lld",&i);
for (j=5;j<=i;j*=5)
{
    p=p+i/j;
}
```

counts the number of factor `5` in all the integers in `[1, i]` and stores the result in `p`.

- Loop 1: `j=5`, `p+=i/5` counts numbers that are divisible by `5` in the range `[1, i]`
- Loop 2: `j=25`, `p+=i/25` counts numbers that are divisible by `25` in the range `[1, i]` (notice that such numbers have been already counted once in loop 1)
- Loop 3: `j=125`, `p+=i/125` counts numbers that are divisible by `125` in the range `[1, i]` (notice that such numbers have been already counted twice in loop 1 and 2)
- ....